# xml to json conversion using json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following simple xml to json conversion code

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument=new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<Root><Record><Column>1</Column></Record></Root>");
string val=JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument,Formatting.None);
```

xml does get converted but the value contains some characters which json invalid.

value contains following

"{\"Root\":{\"Record\":{\"Column\":\"1\"}}}

I do not want those "\" characters in the converted string. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something here?

I suspect you're missing the fact that they're not really there :) I'm sure you're just seeing them in the debugger - which escapes things like quotes for you.

Just print the string to the console, and you'll see what you want.

(I've just tried it myself using your sample code, and it's fine.)

Comment: Jon, thanks for the quick response. But that is the exact text returned to client and also that is the value of string which suggest that they are there.

Comment: I am returning the val to client and this is what I get in Fiddler              HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 04:19:52 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 44
Connection: Close

    "{\"Root\":{\"Record\":{\"Column\":\"1\"}}}"

Comment: @user1901680: Then it sounds like you're double-encoding the data. The value in `val` is correct. (As I say, log it and you'll see it's fine.) You haven't shown how you're returning the data to the client, but if you've declared that you'll return a string *and* that you want the result to be in JSON, that's probably the issue.

Comment: I think you are right. But I don't know how to fix or what to do. Here is the web api code                                                                       public string Get()
        {
            //return (new ResultResponse()).GetData();
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml("<Root><Record><Column>1</Column></Record></Root>");
            string val = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
            return val;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but just try this.. Instead of using Character's use the Predeclared Entity.

```
Character   Predeclared Entity
&              &amp;
<              &lt;
>              &gt;
"              &quot;
'              &apos;
```

For example, the Record name “AT&T” should appear in the XML markup as “AT&T”: the XML parser will take care of changing “&” back to “&” automatically when the document is processed.

Anyone Correct me if I'm wrong...

Thanks.,

Comment: You might have realised by now that stackoverflow does HtmlDecode your responses

Comment: No, the JSON encoding is working fine - the problem is how the OP is returning the data.